# Retrieve correct data from Core Data?

Tags: ios, rest, core-data

I have a REST API and I want to save the responses with Core Data. I was trying to implement [DATAStack](https://github.com/3lvis/DATAStack) and [Sync](https://github.com/hyperoslo/Sync) but I can't understand how they work. I know I can save an object into Core Data and retrieve them. But I don't find how to retrieve the objects related to an specific URL that I requested before

e.g:

```
GET my_url.com/home_page

{
  "posts":[
       {
         "id": 1,
         "title": "Example Post",
       },
       {
         "id": 2,
         "title": "Another example",    
       }    
      ]
}
```

and

```
GET my_url.com/another_page

{
  "posts":[
       {
         "id": 4,
         "title": "This is another post",
       },
       {
         "id": 5,
         "title": "Last Post",    
       }    
      ]
}
```

How do I get data from Core Data related to an URL request?

Comment: How do you want to do it? You need to come up with a scheme and try implementing it. You could save the URL in the returned objects. Or create a new object with a relationship to the objects. Or use the URL caching system...

Comment: @Wain I'm new using Core Data. This is what I want to do:

First, When I enter in a ViewController I request data from server, I show the results and save it in Core Data. Doing this, when close the app and open it again, I go to the same ViewController and I want to get the data from Core Data immediately, while Core Data sync with server response to check if there are changes. 

I have different ViewControllers that return the same json but with different information. I want to know what is the correct way to do it.

Comment: (depending on the data) there is no single correct way to do it. you need to store something that allows you to use a predicate to find the data you want, but you need to decide what that is and how you store it

Comment: Got it. Will try to figure it out. Thanks for your help @Wain. I appreciate it.